# Why does mesos report more allocated CPUs than actual cores?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I'm working with some servers that have 32 cores in them (That's including hyperthreading).  However, when I look at the details for the framework for the node, I've seen several that report more than 32 allocated CPUs.  Why is that?

Edit 1:

Looking at one of the nodes, /proc/cpuinfo lists the correct number of CPUs.  The only framework registered with this node is Marathon and that's where I see the overallocation of CPUs (via the Mesos UI).  Mesos does report I have 32 CPUs.

Comment: If CPU resources aren't configured by user it will be configured according to `/proc/cpuinfo`. Can you confirm this file has proper content?

Comment: @janisz: I updated the question to answer your question.  Thanks.

Comment: How many would you see?

Comment: @blockcipher Can you post response from http://your_mesos_master:5050/master/state. Webui is updated with data returned by this endpoint.

Comment: @hbogert: Looking at one node:

* On the Slaves page, it lists 32 CPUS
* Clicking on the slave, I see under resources some used (varying) and 32 allocated.
* Clicking on the framework running on that node, it's currently telling me 31.9 Allocated.

On others, I've seen numbers like 32.8, 34.0, etc.

Comment: @janisz: Unfortunately, no.  I don't have access to it from this computer.  Is there something specific that you're looking for?

Comment: It will include infrmation about version, tasks, slaves, framewrosk e.t.c. I think I reproduced problem on my local PC. With 4 CPUs I can see that 4.4  CPUs is used. I'm using default settings and state.json looks good but in metrics I see my tasks allocate allocate more resources than I set. It's because Mesos adds [`DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_CPUS`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/d1b681f140fbae58001f96b4b4b8a4a0cadb6a6b/src/slave/slave.cpp#L3993-L4003) to each executor after offer is accepted. So it's possible to get more allocated CPUs than offered.

Comment: @janisz: Moving to comment associated with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [code comment says](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/d1b681f140fbae58001f96b4b4b8a4a0cadb6a6b/src/slave/slave.cpp#L3993-L4003) it's possible to have more allocated CPUs then actually system has. Framework is accepting offer that need to fit into resources constraints but then slave add some non zero resources for executor. So same could happen with MEM.

```
// Default cpu resource given to a command executor.
constexpr double DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_CPUS = 0.1;
// Default memory resource given to a command executor.
constexpr Bytes DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_MEM = Megabytes(32);
...
// Add an allowance for the command executor. This does lead to a
// small overcommit of resources.
// TODO(vinod): If a task is using revocable resources, mark the
// corresponding executor resource (e.g., cpus) to be also
// revocable. Currently, it is OK because the containerizer is
// given task + executor resources on task launch resulting in
// the container being correctly marked as revocable.
executor.mutable_resources()->MergeFrom(
    Resources::parse(
      "cpus:" + stringify(DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_CPUS) + ";" +
      "mem:" + stringify(DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_MEM.megabytes())).get());
```

WebUI shows values taken from `master/metrics` endpoint and values there are calculated form Executor not just tasks.

Comment: Awesome.  I did a search for that variable and found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1718  It looks like this may be resolved in a future release.  It also explains why the current behaviour is the way it is.